# Obtener ID de video de una url youtube usando Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube

Cómo se puede extraer le identificador del video de una url de youtube usando Kotlin

Lo tengo para `PHP` pero no consigo transcribirla para Kotlin, dejo test

```php
<?php
$links = [
    "youtube.com/v/tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtube.com/vi/tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtube.com/?v=tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtube.com/?vi=tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtube.com/watch?v=tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtube.com/watch?vi=tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtu.be/tFad5gHoBjY",
    "http://youtu.be/qokEYBNWA_0?t=30m26s",
    "youtube.com/v/tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtube.com/vi/tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtube.com/?v=tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtube.com/?vi=tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtube.com/watch?v=tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtube.com/watch?vi=tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtu.be/tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtube.com/embed/tFad5gHoBjY",
    "http://youtube.com/v/tFad5gHoBjY",
    "http://www.youtube.com/v/tFad5gHoBjY",
    "https://www.youtube.com/v/tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtube.com/watch?v=tFad5gHoBjY&wtv=wtv",
    "http://www.youtube.com/watch?dev=inprogress&v=tFad5gHoBjY&feature=related",
    "youtube.com/watch?v=7HCZvhRAk-M"
];

foreach($links as $link){
    var_dump( getYouTubeId($link));
}

function getYouTubeId($url) {
    preg_match("#([\/|\?|&]vi?[\/|=]|youtu\.be\/|embed\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)#", $url, $matches);
    return end($matches);
}
```

test online: [sandbox php](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com?s=5ZPvS4NAHIffC_4Ph4uhNOcoKvohskWxXtSLCGJTkZt-p7bp2XmnVNv_3ukkVoy59x14nPjccx8-hzdWFmWydLSM00WOTGTLEhJD-SCc8Rn0fZIYhcHucXAWjsnobaL0dhFxK2IVZjsStzIlZn50gKvh9gj7M9gZOmIsuzKMH-adLO4mo6fXoTewmHk6SE7O890l_Kuati2QzCBoLXNvTQ1YlmX_MDg_mG7ppVuywhRPW5TN1gAKM04zSkIKed79bZoDZpyCSWGJGQR7E1yMb6dF9Dxc6I-KLLnXsiRLc0IB-5Ha_I04R_VK-9p4Cky9gCeZikJgE8JfhPMh2NCaJgzrWsJTn8Uk_QNxutRQI8oohF5SBVGVjmo7xsqxVl23iK1qbbqrOrAjrl681pfrGJpqY_1zqE8H-qWnu8daR-mhyirmWgV5FaHSUxAtpAhScezWp_U3&v=8.1.3)

Seria transcribir a kotlin la función `getYouTubeId`

Comment: ¿Y que has intentado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi solución en [Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/cRgQ4xmnb)

```
fun main() {
    val links = listOf(
        "youtube.com/v/tFad5gHoBjY",
        "youtube.com/vi/tFad5gHoBjY",
        "youtube.com/?v=tFad5gHoBjY",
        "youtube.com/?vi=tFad5gHoBjY",
        "youtube.com/watch?v=tFad5gHoBjY",
        "youtube.com/watch?vi=tFad5gHoBjY",
        "youtu.be/tFad5gHoBjY",
        "http://youtu.be/qokEYBNWA_0?t=30m26s",
        "youtube.com/v/tFad5gHoBjY",
        "youtube.com/vi/tFad5gHoBjY",
        "youtube.com/?v=tFad5gHoBjY",
        "youtube.com/?vi=tFad5gHoBjY",
        "youtube.com/watch?v=tFad5gHoBjY",
        "youtube.com/watch?vi=tFad5gHoBjY",
        "youtu.be/tFad5gHoBjY",
        "youtube.com/embed/tFad5gHoBjY",
        "http://youtube.com/v/tFad5gHoBjY",
        "http://www.youtube.com/v/tFad5gHoBjY",
        "https://www.youtube.com/v/tFad5gHoBjY",
        "youtube.com/watch?v=tFad5gHoBjY&wtv=wtv",
        "http://www.youtube.com/watch?dev=inprogress&v=tFad5gHoBjY&feature=related",
        "youtube.com/watch?v=7HCZvhRAk-M"
    )
    
    for (link in links) {
        println(getYoutubeId(link))
    }
}

val pattern = "([/|?|&]vi?[/|=]|youtu.be/|embed/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)".toRegex()

fun getYoutubeId(url: String) : String?{
    return pattern.find(url)?.groupValues?.last()
}
```

---

1. Primero escribí el patrón sin los backslash ya que solo serían
   necesarios si usaras algún escape sequence (como *\W* o *\s* por
   ejemplo) y en cuyo caso podrías usar una *raw String* para no tener
   que usar varios backslash, por ejemplo: `"""a[bc]+d?\W"""`. En este caso no es
   necesario pero lo comento por si sirve.
   El patrón queda `"([/|?|&]vi?[/|=]|youtu.be/|embed/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)"`
2. Después se pasa el string a Regex con el método `.toRegex()` de los
   strings.
3. Una vez que tenemos el patrón como Regex, podemos usar `.matches()`,
   `.find()`, `.findAll()`, etc. Usando `.find()` nos devuelve una secuencia de MatchResult nulable, por lo que obtengo los `groupValues`, una lista con los substrings que matchearon con el patrón.
4. Finalmente uso `.last()` porque el grupo que nos interesa es el
   ultimo, el del Id